# AWS node SDK for Social Logins using Cognito UserPools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I have a mobile app with signup/signin options. Mobile app makes calls to Rest APIs and the APIs use Node's @aws-sdk CognitoIdentityProvider client to create users in AWS Cognito user pools. SignIn using email/password works fine.

For social sign-in, mobile app is updated with google sign-in and fetch idToken,accessToken. How do I use google returned idToken token to signin/create user in Cognito user pool from the backend node environment? Is this feasible?

For username/password options, I use signup and adminInitiateAuth methods. But not sure what to use to allow users to sign or create users in UserPool when using google/facebook signin option.

Essentially is there a way in aws-sdk or other AWS libraries to create users in UserPool using google/facebook returned idToken>